# How can i implement 2 html theme in same angular project

Tags: angular

I want to use different html theme for my angular blog project. One is for front view and another is for admin view. but how can i do it? If i use my all html and js inside angular.json file html does not work correctly. What is the solution

Answer (score 0):

it is already a good time to make use of css variables. they are supported for almost all users. lets say you have main and secondary color.
default theme file could look like this

```
document {
  --my-main-color: #aabbcd;
  --my-secondary-color: green;
}
```

component.css

```
.element {
  background: var(--my-main-color);
}

.input {
  background: var(--my-secondary-color);
}
```

than you can overwrite value of any "theme property" through changing style of `html` element